# Automatic authorization for Hub pull request from command line

Tags: git, bash, github, github-api

I am attempting to make pull requests using Hub from the command line. I have installed using brew and put this line in my `.bash_profile`.

```
eval "$(hub alias -s)"
```

When I reload my bash profile I get this line:

```
-bash: alias.uncommit: command not found
```

This seems to reference an alias that I have in my git config. Hub seems to work at this point in that I can call any git command using hub, including the one that it threw an error on above.

I then added a git alias for hub pull-request that looks like this:

```
pr = !hub pull-request
```

This seems to be working up to a point. I can run g pr and it asks me for my git credentials to try and run the pull request. At this point I copied the git-pr file from Thoughtbot dotfiles.

https://github.com/christoomey/dotfiles/blob/7389bc317c1a48ed289ff621c83eec83f3bdf8f5/bin/git-pr

I am unsure how to activate or include this file. I am still being asked for my git credentials when I run the g pr command and do not think it is using the ThoughtBot file.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, at long last I've come across the answer to my own question.

I followed the instructions in this link:

https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/

and it all works seamlessly. The key is the osxkeychain that stores your credentials. Now the git aliases work with hub, so I can run 'g pr' and it runs !hub pull-request -o behind the scenes and creates a pull request up on github and then opens it for me. Love it.